# My Laptop won't work correctly with monitors but it works with the TV

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

My laptop (hp omen) was working fine with my Dell monitor at 1440x900 with 60Hz, all of the sudden I get those red flickery pixels

[image]

Then I tried connecting my other laptop(Lenovo) to the same monitor and it works perfectly fine. so my monitor wasn't the problem

So I connected my hp laptop to my living room tv and it works, so I asume it wasn't my hdmi output

- Tried reinsatalling the drivers (intel graphic and Nvidia 960M)
- I boot with an ubuntu OS and the error kept going
- I format my entire laptop and reinstall Windows 10 again
- Test with another monitor, and works fine

I'm using an HDMI DVI Cable

At this point I don't know what else to do

Comment: The HDMI-to-DVI cable is bad. That's the only thing that you haven't tried swapping out or trying on two different devices, right?

Comment: @n8te I tried the same cable in my lenovo laptop and display perfectly fine

Comment: Oh ok. Hmmm. In the pic it looks like what you see when it's a bad cable.

Comment: Have you tested the monitor with another computer?